# How to use toSing from singletons library?

Tags: haskell, singleton, dependent-type, data-kinds

I'm a newbie when it comes to the `singleton` library, and *may* have bitten off more than I can chew here.

I've managed to use `fromSing` successfully to convert a "singleton type" to a "value-level term" (is my terminology correct?) However, I'm unable to understand how to use `toSing` and *conceptually* how it would convert a value **at run-time** to a type?

Here's what the docs for [`toSing`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-12.1/singletons-2.4.1/Data-Singletons.html#v:toSing) say, which I don't really understand...

```
-- Convert an unrefined type to an existentially-quantified singleton type.
toSing :: Demote k -> SomeSing k
```

Here's what `SomeSing` says:

```
-- An existentially-quantified singleton. This type is useful 
-- when you want a singleton type, but there is no way of knowing, 
-- at compile-time, what the type index will be. To make use of this 
-- type, you will generally have to use a pattern-match:

foo :: Bool -> ...
foo b = case toSing b of
          SomeSing sb -> {- fancy dependently-typed code with sb -}
```

Does this mean that *conceptually*, `fromSing` is basically doing the following:

```
data RuntimeValue = Value1 | Value2

someFunction :: RuntimeValue -> UnifiedType a
case runtimeValue of
  Value1 -> someAction (Proxy :: Proxy 'Value1)
  Value2 -> someAction (Proxy :: Proxy 'Value2)
```

And that is the best that one can expect from Haskell, as of today? i.e. we need to pattern-match on the runtime value, run functions that can be of different types, but ultimately they should unify to a single type?

Answer (score 3):

If you compile the code:

```
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -Wall #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

module SingletonExample where
import Data.Singletons.TH
singletons [d| data Value = Value1 | Value2 |]
```

with the flags `-ddump-splices -dsuppress-uniques`, you can see the actual code the `singletons` library is generating via Template Haskell.  In particular, the generated `SingKind` instance is:

```
instance SingKind Value where
  type Demote Value = Value
  fromSing SValue1 = Value1
  fromSing SValue2 = Value2
  toSing Value1 = SomeSing SValue1
  toSing Value2 = SomeSing SValue2
```

So, `fromSing` and `toSing` are just boilerplate conversion functions from (runtime) values to (runtime) singletons and back.

That is, `fromSing` and `toSing` don't convert between values and types, they convert between values and singletons.  You typically use `toSing` when you have a function that's been written to require a singleton:

```
g :: SValue value -> String
g SValue1 = "one"
g SValue2 = "two"
```

but all you have is an associated value.  In this case, you can use the somewhat awkward construct:

```
f :: Value -> String
f v = case toSing v of SomeSing sv -> g sv
```

to call `g` with the requisite singleton.

It turns out that for the usual use cases for singletons, there are only a few situations where this works and/or is helpful.  As a result, it's actually pretty rare to see `toSing` used in singleton code.  And, in particular, it's neither necessary nor very often particularly useful to use `toSing` when working with types that are runtime-dependent.

Ultimately, if you want to learn/understand the `singletons` library, you need to understand when and why singletons are useful (and the complex and subtle sense in which they are runtime representations of types), not how to convert back and forth between them and their associated values.  To that end, I suggest reading the [Hasochism](https://personal.cis.strath.ac.uk/conor.mcbride/pub/hasochism.pdf) paper, [Dependently Typed Programming with Singletons](https://cs.brynmawr.edu/~rae/papers/2012/singletons/paper.pdf), searching for "dependently typed programming in haskell" and or "haskell singletons" and reading every blog post you see.  Weirich has some [YouTube videos](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=stephanie+weirich) that would be worth checking out, too.

Comment: Thank you, yet again, for the insightful comment. I've already ordered a print of the paper (or was it a PhD thesis), titled `Dependent Types In Haskell: Theory and Practice` (by Richard A. Eisenberg, who I believe, is the author of the `singletons` library). The paper that you've linked to, is much shorted and I'll definitely give it a read. In the meantime, is my intuition correct: a singleton is a type with exactly one value. So, if you know the value (at runtime), you also know the type.

Comment: I think I'm unable to appreciate/understand the following: `That is, fromSing and toSing don't convert between values and types, they convert between values and singletons. You typically use toSing when you have a function that's been written to require a singleton:` Why would one want to work with `SValue value` or `SomeSing k`? Is it to write functions that can accept _any_ singleton? For example, `data Perms = Perm1 | Perm2 ; data Features = Feature1 | Feature2`, and I want to write a function that can work with a `x :: Perms` kind OR `y :: Features` kind?

Comment: The type `SValue value` can have one of two values: `SValue1` or `SValue2`, and similarly `SomeSing Value` can only be `SomeSing SValue1` or `SomeSing SValue2`, so you work with those when you want to write a function to accept a singleton for types of kind `Value`.

Comment: Re: your intuition. Yes, that's true, though "know" is a pretty vague term, so it might be more accurate to say: if you inspect (pattern match) the value at the term level, you make type information (type equality constraints) available at the type level.